# How concatenate the link_to in helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to make it work ?

I need `puts` the two links.

Concatenation `<<` with `link_to` does not.

```
module ItemHelper

    def edit_links
        if user_signed_in? && @item.user_id == current_user.id
            html << link_to edit_item_path(@item), class: 'ui button small' do
                "<i class='icon edit'></i> Edit"
            end
            html << link_to item_photos_path(@item), class: 'ui button small' do
                "<i class='icon photo'></i> Photo"
            end
            html
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30522958/3185510

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start with something before you can append to it with `<<`, and then you'll need to call `#html_safe` to prevent Rails from escaping the HTML.

```
if user_signed_in? && @item.user_id == current_user.id
  html = ""
  html << link_to "<i class='icon edit'></i> Edit", edit_item_path(@item), class: 'ui button small'
  html << link_to "<i class='icon photo'></i> Photo", item_photos_path(@item), class: 'ui button small'
  html.html_safe
end
```

Comment: What's the output you see when you call `edit_links`?

Answer (score 0):

The `<<` operator is actually pushing an object onto an array. It also looks like the `html` variable is not defined yet. You create the array before your first link, then join it after your last, you should have what you need.

```
def edit_links
  if user_signed_in? && @item.user_id == current_user.id
    html = []
    # ... existing logic
    html.join
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_link(link_text, link_source)
  link_to link_source, { class: 'ui button small' } do
    "#{content_tag :i, nil, class: 'iicon photo'} #{link_text}".html_safe
  end
end
```

Create a helper method in application_helper and using that you can create your link_to tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def edit_links
  if user_signed_in? && @item.user_id == current_user.id
     link_1 = link_to edit_item_path(@item), class: 'ui button small' do
       "<i class='icon edit'></i> Edit".html_safe
     end
     link_2 = link_to item_photos_path(@item), class: 'ui button small' do
       "<i class='icon photo'></i> Photo".html_safe
     end
     link = link_1 + link_2
  end
end
```